# Plotting wind barbs in python (no U,V component)

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, wind, python

I've got 4 different .txt files for longitude, latitude, wind speed and wind direction (so no U and V components of the wind). Is there any way to plot wind barbs from such a dataset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7012/plotting-wind-barbs-in-python

Comment: If that answer doesn't satisfy you because it is specifically for u,v wind then maybe you should do the transition from speed and direction to u,v first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting wind barbs in python](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7012/plotting-wind-barbs-in-python)

Comment: @Communisty I don't think it's a duplicate. The other question is mainly about how to read the data out of a netCDF file. This question is about how to convert some wind data from polar to Cartesian co-ordinates for plotting (though not phrased in those terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer this in two steps

1. Calculate $u$ and $v$. This [site](http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m430/Wind/WindDirection.html) has formulas for $u$ and $v$. They are as follows: $$u=-|\vec{v}|\sin(\frac{\pi}{180}\phi)$$ and $$v=-|\vec{v}|\cos(\frac{\pi}{180}\phi)$$
   where $\phi$ is the wind direction in the meteorological system, and $|\vec{v}|$ is the wind speed.
2. Having calculated $u$ and $v$, you can plot the wind barbs by following the example found at [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barb_demo.html) site.

Comment: Thank you for that. In addition to my previous question. Having lat, lon, u, v wind txt files, how could I use matplotlib in order to plot the wind barbs on a map (let's say UK map). I read the links that you gave me, but as I am newbie in python I can't find the way.

Comment: Sure. In addition to those links, try looking here: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html. The idea is to make a basemap with whatever projection & parameters you want, use it to convert to longitude & latitude to x & y, and plot the barbs on the basemap.

Comment: I finaly found the solution, doing sth like that:


m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=33,urcrnrlat=43,\
            llcrnrlon=18,urcrnrlon=30,lat_ts=20,resolution='i')
jet = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
x,y = m(lon, lat)
barbs = m.barbs(x,y,wind_u,wind_v,wind_spd_knots, cmap=jet,length=7,linewidth=0.8,pivot='middle')


However I can't find how to set limints on the colorscale for example like setting vmin, vmax. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Did you try levels= <array>, such as what contour and contourf use?

Comment: No. Could you explain that please?

Comment: So `levels=np.arange(0,5)` for example, will make contours at 0-4 in increments of 1. That is generally the other option to vmin and vmax. However, I am unsure of why you are trying to color the barbs. If that doesn't work, you could devise a brute force way of coloring the wind barbs.

Comment: It seems to be quite random. I am not sure how it works. I guess the problem is that in this command:

barbs = m.barbs(x,y,wind_u,wind_v, lelvels ,length=7,linewidth=0.8,pivot='middle')

there are two lists instead of just one, wind_u and wind_v. So the colorscale can't refer to the combination of u and v winds.

Comment: After looking through the demo (provided in the answer) I found a couple of different things. `levels` likely won't work. Try using things like `barb_increments` and `barbcolor` as seen in the example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barb_demo.html.

Comment: It seems that barb_increments sets the shape od wind barbs for specific values. Barbcolors cannot set specific colors for specific value.

Comment: barb_increments is a dictionary that tells Python what the different flags and barbs mean. I am unsure what the colors represent. You may want to play around with that, or just set one standard color.

Comment: Finally I found it. Using clim=[0,50], I set the range between 0 and 50 knots. the very last thing is how to plot the colorbar. plt.colorbar doesn't work.

I also found an alternative way by plotting arrows:
sc=m.quiver(x,y,wind_u,wind_v, wind_spd_knots,cmap=jet,clim=[0,50])

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus What is the equation for calculating meteorological wind angle from latitude and longitude ?

Comment: @gansub What do you mean? Latitude and longitude are static variables, whereas wind angle changes with time. The meteorological wind angle would be what is reported on a METAR, and the mathematical wind angle would be $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)$. If you follow the website, it shows the equations in more detail.

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus So the question should perhaps be edited ? There is no use for latitude and longitude then. OP should mention meteorological wind angle as input ?

Answer (score 3):

The data format you have (magnitude and direction) is usually referred to as *polar co-ordinates*. The data format you need (horizontal and vertical offsets) is *Cartesian co-ordinates*. There's plenty of good material on this online. For a friendly introduction, see e.g. [this page on "Math is Fun!"](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html) (or your favourite high-school maths textbook).

Converting between the two systems involves a bit of simple trigonometry, and the exact formulae depend on how you're measuring the angle in your polar co-ordinates. Mathematicians tend to measure anticlockwise from the positive x axis in radians. Geoscientists usually measure clockwise from the positive y axis in degrees (like a compass bearing):

[image: polar co-ordinates]
<sup>Source: [kartoweb.itc.nl](https://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Coordinate%20systems/coordsys.html)</sup>

Assuming that this is the convention used in your data, the conversion formulae are refreshingly straighforward.

$x = d\sin(\alpha)$
$y = d\cos(\alpha)$

One thing to watch out for: like most programming languages, Python uses radians, not degrees, for its trigonometric functions. If your angles are in degrees, don't forget to run them through the `math.radians()` function before taking sines and cosines!

Incidentally, having each measurement in a *separate* text-file is probably a recipe for inconvenience and confusion. If I were you, I'd have "combine measurements as columns in a single file" as the first step in my processing workflow.